# Run program if drive is mounted, and exit

Tags: autohotkey

I am using this script to run a program if X:\ is mounted, and exit the app when X:\ is no longer mounted. How can I optimise it?

```
DriveGet, status, Status, X:\
if (status = "Ready")
    Run ~
SetTimer, RunTheScript, 500
return

RunTheScript:
DriveGet, status, Status, X:\
if (status = "Ready")
  return
; Otherwise:
SetTimer, RunTheScript, off
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Persistent ; keeps the script permanently running 
SetTimer, RunCloseProgram, 500
    return

    RunCloseProgram:
If (FileExist("X:\") && (!ProcessExist("notepad.exe"))) ; "&&" means "AND" and "!" means "NOT"
    Run notepad
If (!FileExist("X:\") && (ProcessExist("notepad.exe")))
    Process Close, notepad.exe
return

ProcessExist(name){
Process, Exist, %name%
return Errorlevel
}
```

EDIT:
If you only need the script to unmount the volume, try this:

```
#Persistent

If !(FileExist("X:\")) 
{
    MsgBox, "X:\" doesn't exist
    ExitApp
}
; Otherwise:
If (!ProcessExist("program.exe"))
    Run path of the program.exe
Process, wait, program.exe
Sleep, 10000
SetTimer, CloseProgram, 500
    return

    CloseProgram:
If (!FileExist("X:\"))
{
    SetTimer, CloseProgram, off
    Sleep, 10000   ;  or more (allow sufficient time for X:\ to dismount)
    Process Close, program.exe
    ExitApp
}
return

ProcessExist(name){
Process, Exist, %name%
return Errorlevel
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned that "notepad" is a program that dismounts X:\, so I do not need the second if-statement. How should I allow sufficient time for X:\ to dismount to avoid "notepad" running indefinitely, and allow the script to exit?

Comment: Try the edited answer (If I understand you correctly).